# Very strange behavior of the Pine Script language?

Tags: pine-script

I have this simple script in a program that doen't work:

```
eurgbp = security("EURGBP",tf,src,lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
var float EUR = 0

// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Incremento %
calc_incrP(src) => (100*(src-src[1])/src[1])
if (mode == MO8)
    var float ROC_eur = 0
    ROC_eur := ROC_eur + calc_incrP(eurgbp) 
    EUR := ROC_eur
```

the program cannot calculate "calc_incrP (eur gbp)". Even replacing with "roc (eurgbp, 1)" I always get "n.d."

If I replace:

```
    ROC_eur := ROC_eur + calc_incrP(eurgbp)
```

with:

```
    ROC_eur := ROC_eur + 0.001        //0.001 for example, it works with any number
```

it works..

I can not continue my program for this problem which seems to me really absurd .. what is it wrong?

Thank's
Piero

Answer (score 1):

On the very first bar, there is no `src[1]` so it will return `na`.
Any calculation with `na` will result in `na`.
You assign that to `ROC_eur`, so that will always be `na`.

Try this:

```
calc_incrP(src) => na(src[1]) ? 0 : 100 * change(src) / src[1]
```

**Edit 1**
This works.

```
calc_incrP(src) => nz(100 * change(src) / src[1])
```

Comment: interesting consideration, I did the test with your function but always it returns n.d ...

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your entire script please? That way we can investigate better.

Comment: done, 
the part that doesn't work is "MO8 ="% Increment "" everything else works

Comment: search the "// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Incremento %"line..

Comment: Added Edit 1 section to my answer, with working function.